# Define a type variable as either one of two options

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle/HOL, we would like to define multi-variable polynomials over either the naturals or the integers. Is there a way to write

`datatype ('a::???) polynomial = ...`

and specify that `'a` should be either `nat` or `int`? A syntax like `'a::nat|int` would seem intuitive at first, but unfortunately doesn't work.

A possible alternative would be to specify `'a::comm_semiring` (possibly also adding `countable`) but we don't really need the full generality of abstract commutative semirings.

Comment: A possible solution would be to define your own class `class coefficient = ...`, then two instances `instantiation nat :: coefficient ...` and `instantiation int :: coefficient ...`, and finally the type `datatype ('a::coefficient) polynomial = ...` .

Comment: Don't you like the already existing multi-variable polynomials even if there are more general than you need?

Comment: @MathiasFleury We require two different types of variables (unknowns and parameters). This would be possible with the [AFP entry](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Polynomials.html) I suppose you're referring to, by using an additional set of indices (or two) marking which is which. We still have to gauge which approach is going to be less cumbersome.